# Android Wear (Maven): No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowSwipeToDismiss'

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, wear-os

I built an Android Wear app in Android Studio, but now decided to build it with **Maven**. There were no compilation errors when building in Android Studio. But now, I am facing the following error when building with Maven:

```
[INFO] [path-to-project]\target\unpacked-libs\com.google.android.support_wearable_aar_1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:127: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowSwipeToDismiss'. 
[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
```

Here are the dependencies I am using:

```
<!-- Android -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.4W.2_r2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v13</artifactId>
    <version>21.0.0</version>
    <type>aar</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- /Android -->

<!-- Android Wear Support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-services-wearable</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>22.0.0</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>wearable</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>aar</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>recyclerview-v7</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Apparently android:windowSwipeToDismiss is not identifiable. I noticed that this attribute was added in API level 20 or so. But the target is set to 21 in my Manifest.xml. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the **SDK version** of the Android Maven Plugin. The error was happening because the sdk version was declared in Android Resources Plugin instead of AMP (typo).